# php echo if two conditions are true

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, file-exists

The actual code looks like this:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {echo $player;

} else { 

echo 'something';
```

but it displays the player even if the id is not called from the url

i need something like this:

```
check if $filename exists and $id it is not empty then echo $player

if else echo something else
```

i check if $id is not empty with

```
if(empty($id)) echo "text";
```

but i don't know how to combine both of them

Can somebody help me?

Thank you for all your code examples but i still have a problem:

How i check if $id **is not empty** then echo the rest of code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: you could also read http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp which is a very good tutorial for beginners

Comment: @wesley @Pentium10 i just read everyone answers and they suggest using `!empty($id)`. What is the difference between `!empty($id)` and `$id != ''`. I would like to know because i'm using `$id != ''` on my code. Both seems the same to me, am i missing something?

Comment: @atno [See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (!empty($id) && file_exists($filename))
```

Comment: i have a little problem: how do i check if it is not empty?

Comment: @m3tsys `!empty($id)` translates to if $id is not empty. that's the answer you're looking for

Comment: thank you. i had some problems whit other code and i tought it is caused from this.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `AND` or `&&` operator to check two conditions:

```
if (file_exists($filename) AND ! empty($id)): // do something
```

It's fundamental PHP. Reading material:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 5):

You need the [logical `AND` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if (file_exists($filename) AND !empty($id)) {
    echo $player;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (file_exists($filename) && !empty($id)){
   echo $player;
}else{
   echo 'other text';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check `$id` along with `file_exists($filename)` as follows

```
if (file_exists($filename) && $id != '') {
echo $player;

} else { 
echo 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary operator:

```
echo (!empty($id)) && file_exists($filename) ? 'OK' : 'not OK';
```

Using if-else clause:

```
if ( (!empty($id)) && file_exists($filename) ) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'not OK';
}
```

Comment: No need for all those parentheses in your examples.

Comment: Just saying FYI. You can add as many as you want like `(((($this))))` and it doesn't make a difference, it more suitable to group conditions like `if ((1 + 1 == 2) && (3 + 3 == 6 AND 6 == 6))`. Yeah bad example, but didn't want a code flood in a comment :)

Comment: I know. But sometimes adding extra parenthesis changes a lot - in terms of understanding code by PHP newcomers. Just wanted to make sure to avoid questions similar to "is `!$a && $b` equal to `!($a && $b)` or `(!$a) && $b`?" ;)