# two different ways for checking if a variable is empty or not

Tags: php, variables

There was a question earlier [php echo if two conditions are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927767/php-echo-if-two-conditions-are-true) and most of the guys answered using the statement `if(!empty($variable)){}` to check if a variable is empty or not while i answered `if($variable != ''){}`. My question is, why most of them answered with `if(!empty($variable)){}`, what are the differences between `if($variable != ''){}` expect readability? Readability is the only difference I'm currently seeing.

Thanks,
atno

Comment: there are lot of question on SO similar to you..please search for that

Comment: Just a note: Be cautious using `empty()`, it can be too broad for some usage. Example: using `empty($_POST['number'])` returns true if the value *is present* but is the actual user input is "0".

Comment: i think i'll stick with `!= ''` for now it's seems "safer" to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R[ead the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

The following things are considered to be empty:

    * "" (an empty string)
    * 0 (0 as an integer)
    * 0.0 (0 as a float)
    * "0" (0 as a string)
    * NULL
    * FALSE
    * array() (an empty array)
    * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

**NOTE::**

Be careful, if "0" (zero as a string), 0 (zero as an integer) and -0 (minus zero as an integer) return true, "-0" (minus zero as a string (yes, I already had some customers that wrote -0 into a form field)) returns false. You need to cast your variable before testing it with the empty() function :

```
<?php
$var = "-0";
echo empty($var);  // returns false
$var = (int) $var; // casts $var as an integer
echo empty($vat);  // returns true
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[empty](http://php.net/empty) also considers variables to be empty if they are a 0-Integer, NULL, FALSE, an empty array (look at the return values). You are only checking if it's not an empty string. You check will return true if the variable is e.g. set to (boolean)FALSE.

Comment: Also returns true for `0` string

Comment: both `$var != ''` and `~empty($var)` returns the same result. Did i F up somewhere? `$var = FALSE;

if($var != ''){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}

if(!empty($var)){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}

$var = 0;

if($var != ''){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}

if(!empty($var)){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}

$var = TRUE;

if($var != ''){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}

if(!empty($var)){
echo 'Not empty';
}else{
echo 'Empty';
}`